# Bind Enter key to Button (PyGObject)

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I'm writing a very simple GUI program for educational purposes. The window has a Gtk.Entry area, from which I grab the input and use as argument for the function num_check(), which checks whether the number is odd or even (and outputs an error if the input is invalid).

The button works fine, but **I want to be able to use the Enter key** instead of the mouse. And after pressing Enter, the focus should return to the input box (Gtk.Entry)

Here's the code. I appreciate any help.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
import odd_even

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="ODD OR EVEN")
        self.set_size_request(200, 100)

        self.timeout_id = None

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.get_text()
        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Go")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click_me_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.get_text()
        vbox.pack_start(self.label, True, True, 0)

# after pressing "Go", grab text from entry and run num_check() with it, then set label with the result
    def on_click_me_clicked(self, button):
        number = self.entry.get_text()
        func = odd_even.num_check(number)
        print(func)

        self.label.set_text(func)


win = EntryWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
import odd_even

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="ODD OR EVEN")
        self.set_size_request(200, 100)

        self.timeout_id = None

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.get_text()
        self.entry.connect("activate", self.on_entry_activate)
        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Go")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click_me_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.get_text()
        vbox.pack_start(self.label, True, True, 0)

    def on_entry_activate (self, entry):
        number = entry.get_text()
        func = odd_even.num_check(number)
        print(func)

        self.label.set_text(func)

# after pressing "Go", grab text from entry and run num_check() with it, then set label with the result
    def on_click_me_clicked(self, button):
        number = self.entry.get_text()
        func = odd_even.num_check(number)
        print(func)

        self.label.set_text(func)


win = EntryWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Edit: the docs for the signals are [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate).

Comment: This worked, thanks. What is the difference between "activate" and "clicked"? What does an activated Entry mean? I'm reading [this documentation](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on PyGObject but I couldn't find much about it. It seems PyGTK and Tkinter are more popular.

Comment: The button "clicked" is not hard to understand (an entry has no "clicked" for your information). The entry "activate" happens when you type into the entry and press the enter key. The button "activate" happens when you focus on the button and press the space bar or similar actions but that is a whole different question.

Comment: PyGtk is not really more popular. It is older, therefore there are more examples for it. In reality PyGtk is no longer developed.